# Designing a Swift algorithm for parallel execution on mac os X

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, macos, parallel-processing

-- Short version --

What is the best way to parallelize an algorithm that performs pairwise comparisons between elements of a large array in Swift so that multiple cores are exploited?

-- Long version --

I am developing an algorithm that performs pairwise comparisons between the elements of a (large) array and removes from the array the elements that don't satisfy a given condition. Once an element is discarded, we don't need to consider it for further comparisons.
This is a simple quadratic algorithm, whose standard implementation could look like this:

```
func nonParallelComputation(dataSet: [Point]) -> [Point] {
    var discarded = [Bool](repeating: false, count: dataSet.count)
    for i in 0..<dataSet.count {
        if discarded[i] { continue }
        let p1 = dataSet[i] // first point of the comparison

        // try all possible second points
        for j in 0..<dataSet.count {
            if i == j || discarded[j] { continue }
            let p2 = dataSet[j] // second point of the comparison
            discarded[j] = p1.betterThan(point: p2)
        }
    }
    // filtering the dataset
    return dataSet.enumerated().filter { !discarded[$0.offset] }.map { $0.element }
}
```

Don't mind too much the details of the implementation, which has been largely simplified anyway. The core is the `discarded` array of `Bool`s, which is used to mark the elements of the array for removal.

I thought I might exploit the 8 cores of my Mac and try to parallelize the execution as much as possible. For instance, I could split the array in 8 blocks, perform the comparisons between the elements of the block and all the other ones in the array, and run those comparisons in parallel (e.g., by using `DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform`), by taking care of synchronizing access to the shared `discarded` array (here I used a lock queue).

A naive parallel version of the above code is shown below:

```
func parallelComputation(dataSet: [Point]) -> [Point] {
    var discarded = [Bool](repeating: false, count: dataSet.count)
    let numberOfParallelThreads = 8
    let lockQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "myQueue")
    DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: numberOfParallelThreads) { iteration in
        let stride = Int(ceil(Double(dataSet.count) / Double(numberOfParallelThreads)))
        let firstIndex = iteration * stride
        let lastIndex = min((iteration + 1) * stride, dataSet.count)
        guard firstIndex < lastIndex else { return }
        for i in firstIndex..<lastIndex {
            var firstPointDiscardedCheck = false
            lockQueue.sync() {
                firstPointDiscardedCheck = discarded[i]
            }
            if firstPointDiscardedCheck { continue }
            let p1 = dataSet[i] // first point of the comparison

            // try all possible second points
            for j in 0..<dataSet.count {
                let p2 = dataSet[j] // second point of the comparison
                var secondPointDiscardedCheck = false
                lockQueue.sync() {
                    secondPointDiscardedCheck = discarded[j]
                }
                if i == j || secondPointDiscardedCheck { continue }
                if p1.betterThan(point: p2) {
                    lockQueue.sync() {
                        discarded[j] = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // filtering the dataset
    return dataSet.enumerated().filter { !discarded[$0.offset] }.map { $0.element }
}
```

This approach does not work well because, evidently, too much time is spent for locking the array, so that the performance worsens dramatically in the parallel version.

I then thought of not only splitting the array in blocks but also of limiting the comparisons to elements of a given block with elements of another given block, so that virtually no locks are needed while comparing pairs of elements. Basically, I'd do 8 iterations. On the first iteration, I'd compare elements of block 1 with those of block 1, and, in parallel, elements of block 2 with elements of block 2, and, in parallel, ... until elements of block 8 with elements of block 8. On the second iteration, I'd compare elements of block 1 with elements of block 2, and, in parallel, elements of block 2 with elements of block 3, etc. At the end of each iteration, I'd update the `discarded` array.
This has the desired benefits in terms of performance (for larger arrays only), but seems overly complex (see the code below).

**EDIT: I'm adding the code here, but I'm not satisfied with this solution**

```
func parallelComputationInBlocks(dataSet: [Point]) -> [Point] {
    var discarded = [Bool](repeating: false, count: dataSet.count)
    let numberOfParallelThreads = 8
    let lockQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "myQueue")

    for block in 0..<numberOfParallelThreads {
        DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: numberOfParallelThreads) { iteration in
            let stride = Int(ceil(Double(dataSet.count) / Double(numberOfParallelThreads)))

            // computing the bounds for the block of the first point
            let firstIndex1 = iteration * stride
            let lastIndex1 = min((iteration + 1) * stride, dataSet.count)
            guard firstIndex1 < lastIndex1 else { return }

            // computing the bounds for the block of the second point
            let firstIndex2 = ((iteration + block) % numberOfParallelThreads) * stride
            let lastIndex2 = min((((iteration + block) % numberOfParallelThreads) + 1) * stride, dataSet.count)
            guard firstIndex2 < lastIndex2 else { return }

            // local, non-shared copies of the discarded array for the relevant blocks
            var discarded1 = [Bool](repeating: false, count: lastIndex1 - firstIndex1)
            var discarded2 = [Bool](repeating: false, count: lastIndex2 - firstIndex2)

            // synchronizing the local copies before the comparisons
            lockQueue.sync() {
                discarded1[0..<lastIndex1-firstIndex1] = discarded[firstIndex1..<lastIndex1]
                discarded2[0..<lastIndex2-firstIndex2] = discarded[firstIndex2..<lastIndex2]
            }

            for i in firstIndex1..<lastIndex1 {
                if discarded1[i-firstIndex1] { continue }
                let p1 = dataSet[i] // first point of the comparison

                // try all possible second points
                for j in firstIndex2..<lastIndex2 {
                    let p2 = dataSet[j] // second point of the comparison
                    if i == j || discarded2[j - firstIndex2] { continue }
                    if p1.betterThan(point: p2) {
                        discarded2[j - firstIndex2] = true
                    }
                }
            }

            // synchronizing the modified array after the comparisons
            lockQueue.sync() {
                discarded[firstIndex2..<lastIndex2] = discarded2[0..<(lastIndex2-firstIndex2)]
            }
        }
    }
    // filtering the dataset
    return dataSet.enumerated().filter { !discarded[$0.offset] }.map { $0.element }
}
```

Albeit 3-4 times faster than the non-parallel solution for large enough arrays, this solution has at least two problems: 1) it looks overly complex, and 2) it hard-codes the desired number of parallel threads.

There must be a better (and simpler) way.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You're comparing every element with every other element twice. Is this intentional?

Comment: Can you sort it first using multiple cores? Will that help your pair-wise comparison?

Comment: @Alexander Yes, that's intentional: in this setting, two elements may also be incomparable.

Comment: @sdasdadas Normally, I can already assume the dataset to be sorted, but this is orthogonal to the problem (in fact, I've also tried to use a set instead of an array of elements plus an array of flags, but that turned out to be slower). Here my focus is how to best parallelize things

Comment: Whats the actual condition for discard/keep? And how big is the array? This would probably be faster with map or reduce or if you used sets and some custom equatable implementation, or even maybe matrix operations with Accelerate. Interesting question.

Comment: @twiz_ The actual condition is very complex, but it's similar to the notion of dominance used in skylines. You may think of `Point` as a d-dimensional vector, and a point p1 dominates another point p2 if it is at least as good as p2 in every dimension, and strictly better in at least one dimension. However my question aimed to be as independent as possible of the specificity of the problem, with the goal of understanding how to best design similar algorithms for parallel/concurrent execution. The array could be as large as 10^6 points. Could you pls elaborate on using map and reduce with sets?

Comment: Yes I'm hoping you get a good answer about splitting an algorithm into multiple threads, I haven't done that and would love to see it.  But to the point about the comparison - if you're only keeping points that are better than every other point, the final array will be only the best vector, and any vector exactly equivalent to it, no?

Comment: Sorry, I keep editing my comments. I see now what dominance in skylines is. Are you restricting it to k-dominance, or looking at every feature? Also, what is the range of dimensions?

Comment: @twiz_ Yes, dominance is not a total order, so you can have multiple points in a skyline. I'm not restricting to k-dominance, although I'm not exactly computing skylines, here. The features are reals between 0 and 1 - but that's irrelevant, as you can always normalize into such an interval.

Comment: I meant what is d, the number of dimensions in each vector.

Comment: d is typically between 2 and 10, but could be even higher